# Connect and pass Auth token to a SignalR hub with CORS enabled

Tags: oauth-2.0, signalr, cors, asp.net-web-api2

I have three ASP.NET WebAPI endpoints:

1. Identity server, which generates bearer tokens (serverA.com);
2. SignalR server with hub (serverB.com);
3. Some endpoint with a simple ASP.NET MVC view and SignalR JS client script (serverC.com).

All three servers use OAuth2 middleware as Auth mechanism. Microsoft.Owin.Cors is configured as well.
Servers use only HTTPS requests.
SignalR v2.2.0 is installed on serverB.com.

I can successfully make a cross-domain request from serverC.com to serverA.com to get bearer token, but, actually, I don't know how to pass auth token while connecting to serverB.com

There are two ways I found so far:

1. Pass auth token as a query string (not secure);
2. Apply this setting to the jQuery.ajax

   $.ajaxSetup({
   beforeSend: function (xhr) {
       xhr.setRequestHeader('tokenKey', 'tokenValue');
   }});

but it forces SignalR to use long polling only.

Is there any other way to send auth token (not in query string) so it can be consumed and validated by OAauth BearerAuthorizationProvider? Maybe, cookies, headers or any other way?

**Update**

CORS middleware set up for both environments to allow all data and accept credentials.

Here is my OWIN middleware:

```
var requestUri = context.Request.Uri.AbsolutePath;
if (string.Equals(requestUri, authRoute, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
     if (!context.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("Authorization") || string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request.Headers["Authorization"]))
     {
           context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
     }
     else
     {
           context.Response.Cookies.Append("BearerToken", context.Request.Headers["Authorization"]);
     }
  }
  else
  {
      await Next.Invoke(context);
  }
```

Then I do first Ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
        url: self.communicationHubUrl + '/authenticate',
        type: 'post',
        cache: false,
        crossDomain: true,
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
             xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', self.accessToken);
       });
```

middleware sets auth token from header to the response cookies.

Then I call hub.Start so SignalR begins to send ajax requests.

But for some reasons I don't quite understand, cookies are present in request only if I enable xhr.withCredentials = true for ALL ajax requests via $.ajaxSetup

```
        $.ajaxSetup({
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            }
        });
```

Without this setting request doesn't include cookies. On the other hand, I guess it's not a good decision to force all ajax requests to enable such settings.

Furthermore, I've faced strange behavior in Oauth middleware: ValidateIdentity method is not invoked when request from signalR comes so instead of 401 Unauthorized, I'm getting deafult principal.

Comment: SignalR already sets `withCredentials: true` for all of its cross-domain Ajax requests. You should be able to configure withCredentials for just your '/authenticate' request using [xhrFields](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) like you did in ajaxSetup. Can you include your Configuration method in your question? It is important that MapSignalR is called after you setup the Oauth middleware if you want it to run for SignalR requests.

Answer (score 1):

I think that putting the auth token insied a cookie will be your best bet. Unlike the ajaxSetup option, cookies are sent with EventSource and WebSocket requests.

You might need to add some middleware to the SignalR server (serverB.com) that sets the appropriate cookie when you POST the auth token before starting the SignalR connection.

Comment: So you suggest to process some special route like serverB.com/authenticate in a custom OWIN middleware?

Comment: Yes. I believe you will need to create the cookie on the SignalR server, since you typically cannot set cookies in JS for another domain.

Comment: halter73, I've implemented OWIN middleware which intercepts special route to set cookies (domain/communication/authenticate in my case) in this way:                    context.Response.Cookies.Append("BearerToken", context.Request.Headers["Authorization"]); so I can see cookies in a response header like 'Set-Cookie: xxx', but unfortunatelly, when I do a new request, there is no cookies at all. Am I missing something?

Comment: Is the new request without the cookies a SignalR request, a manual Ajax request or some other type request? You should ensure that you set the [xhr.withCredentials](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/#toc-withcredentials) property to true for any CORS requests that need cookies. I would also make sure the server is setting `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` header appropriately.

Comment: Are you setting the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` Header in your /authenticate middleware? I'm pretty sure if you don't, the cookie you're setting will be ignored.

Comment: Yes, I'd set up Microsoft.Owin.Cors to allow everything. Access-Control-Allow-Credentials is set to True as well